# Why do I need to add my application pool identity to the IIS_IUSRS group?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm setting up a .NET v4.0 web application on a Windows 2008 R2/IIS 7.5 server that uses a domain account for the application pool identity. When I access the site, I get the following error:

The current identity () does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files'

According to this: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis/ the identity of the worker process is added to the IIS_IUSRS group when the process starts. This seems to work fine for the existing .NET v2.0 applications I have running on the same server (I have not had to add their domain account application pool identities to IIS_IUSRS group). This does not seem to be the case for the first .NET v4.0 web application I'm setting up.

Once I add the identity to the group, everything works fine. I suspect something is not configured correctly that is forcing me to do this. I would like to understand this before rolling out more sites/servers.

Thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 1):

The user identity does not have rights to access the temp asp.net files.  I have had issues before that were resolved by granting that user ntfs permissions rights to that folder.  Also, temporarily elevate user privileges to see if it is a permission issue.  Then you can check to see if the IIS_ISUSRS group has sufficient permissions to those files.  Don't forget to recycle IIS.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 4 is not automatically registered on IIS even if you install .NET Framework 4. You have to manually execute `aspnet_regiis` before doing anything else,

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

`-i` or `-ir` is enough.